# Dictionary: find min/max values within a range of given keys and returning their keys

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a concurrentdictionary with 500,000 items.
Keys are integers, items are single.

for instance:

```
1, 8.65
2, 7.65
3, 8.89
4, 8.90
5, 7.95
...
500000, 7.68
```

How I can I retrieve the min and max values **within a specified key range** of this dictionary and their respective keys?

Example: finding min/max data value between key=25 and key=477 and returning their keys.

I found some LINQ examples but the author warned it's **potentially slower than foreach**, and not doing exactly what I would like.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/774aa579-2bc9-4458-93f4-af4b94169e7c/get-min-and-max-values-in-dictionary?forum=csharpgeneral

Performance is critical in my application.

**Update 1:**

I want to know the keys corresponding to the max/min.

The dictionary contains a time serie. The values (single) are ordered in time by their key. Higher the key value is, more recent is the data.

**Update 2: benchmarks**

I made a few benchmarks filling a **concurrent dictionary with 929,452 records**.

My CPU is i7-8550U, that means it has boost on single thread (3.8GHz) and lowers its frequency when the 4 cores (8 threads) run, roughly 2.6 GHz. So, I never expect multithread to be 4 times faster than single thread.

For each item of the dictionary, I look backward for the maximum of the previous 800 records.

Release build mode, x64:

- Single thread, for loop: 14149 ms
- Multithread, parallelfor loop: 4731 ms
- Single thread, linq ONLY 1000 records: 17609 ms. Sorry LINQ.

LINQ is out. Definitively I will go for the "for loop". Now I'd like to compare `concurrentdictionary` and `list of`with the `for loop`.

**Update 3: simplification and benchmarks**

Modifying my code using other containers. All are thread-safe for reading (if no modification by other thread at the same time).

- Concurrent dictionary 1-thread of my objects (datetime, 2D-single): 14682 ms
- List of my objects (datetime, 2D-single): 2071 ms
- Concurrent dictionary 4-threads: 4611 ms
- Array of objects (datetime, 2D-single): 1030 ms
- Array of 1D-single (x4) and array 1D-datetime: 784 ms
- Array of 1D-single (x4) and array 1D-datetime 4 threads: 229 ms.

In order to keep my input objects read-only and as fast as possible, I will have to write the processing results in another object. It's another theme now.

Comment: If you have all the values from 1 to 500000 why not use an array instead?  Then you could do a `for(int i = 24; i <= 476; i++)` (note everything will start as zero so you'd need to do the -1 to get the actual index) and just find the min and max as you go.

Comment: I use the concurrent dictionary because it is supposed thread safe. And I further use the TPL to access it.

Comment: Dictionaries don't buy you very much if you aren't doing exact matches on the keys.

Comment: You need a thread safe container only if it is updated concurrently by multiple threads. If the data are immutable, an array is perfectly safe, and ideal for the ranged queries you would like to perform.

Comment: What size is the expected average range of your queries?

Comment: Should 30 to 1000 elements. I choose a dictionary because it contains objects and not only single datatype. I tried to simplify my problem to present it here in the simplest form.

Comment: `I choose a dictionary because it contains objects and not only single datatype` An array can also contain `object`.

Comment: 30 to 1000 are not that much, and you'll get a decent performance by simply looping over an array. For queries on larger ranges it would make sense to precalculate the min/max of subranges, to speed up the queries at the cost of some space and some added complexity.

Comment: @mjwills yes you are right, but if I try reading/updating part of this array from multiple threads I can have problems. Concurrentdictionary is a threadsafe container.

Comment: I have given sample, but I don't know, how about in your side, it can give your hope result or not, in mine is ok

Comment: The `ConcurrentDictionary` is not a good substitute for an array, particularly for your intended use (looping over ranges). If your data are not immutable, and are frequently updated, consider using a normal array or `List<T>` protected by a [`ReaderWriterLock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlock).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias ok, MS recommends `ReaderWriterLockSlim` over `ReaderWriterLock` I need to run benchmark on `List<T>` vs `ConccurentDictionary`

Comment: [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548406/Dictionary-plus-Locking-versus-ConcurrentDictionar) conclusions of this article tell it's better to use a concurrent dictionary instead of a dictionary + lock if I do more reads than writes. Add and remove are slower with a dictionary+Lock than with a concurrent dictionary. I would have love to find a compromise like a "concurrentlist" but that doesn't exist.

Comment: I posted a custom `ConcurrentList` implementation that can be extended as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure dictionary knows to optimize based on any relationship the keys may have.
As such, I think you're going to have to do the optimizing yourself. With one pass through the dictionary, you should be able to:

```
int max = Int32.MinValue;
int min = Int32.MaxValue,
foreach (var k in dictionary.keys) {
       if (k<minIndex | k>maxIndex) continue;
       max = Math.Max(max,dictionary[k]);
       min = Math.Min(min,dictionary[k]);
}
```

Now if your dictionary is sorted ahead of time, meaning key '50' will always be before key '60', you can abort as soon as possible and start as late as possible.

You should in fact see [SortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2.keys?view=netframework-4.8)

**SINCE you updated your description**

Use a [SortedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist?view=netframework-4.8), k is the index number of the list and the value is your double.

Comment: Don't you mean `if( k > min && k < max) continue;`?  And you need to assign the result of `Math.Max` and `Math.Min` to something.

Comment: @juharr - no if it's in range, I want it to perform the inloop logic, not go to the next key. Good point on the assigning of result though. Hit submit too fast :-)

Comment: You may think that but you’re using concurrent dict in your example, you don’t really know what’s going on behind the scenes, especially with a concurrent class which is likely used from different threads and the iterator is not for certain going in the order you expect.

Comment: I fill the dictionnary with a for loop using a single thread, keys are in order, so for me [newbie], they are always ordered. Aren't they? I use multiple threads to read the data only. @theodor suggested that "concurrent" dictionary isn't useful in that case.

Comment: Assuming it's ordered, I can use a simple for(int i=start key to end key) instead of foreach and not test all keys from the dictionary.

Comment: Yes, but I'd still use SortedDictionary. And as @theodor said, you definitely don't need concurrent in your use case.

Answer (score 2):

The `Where` will return all elements with keys in your range, and then `Max()` and `Min()` methods will return corresponding min and max values in the rage.

```
var data = new Dictionary<int, double>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    data.Add(i, i * 1.1);
}

var minKey = 3;
var maxKey = 7;
var max = data.Where(x => x.Key >= minKey && x.Key <= maxKey).Max(y => y.Value);
var min = data.Where(x => x.Key >= minKey && x.Key <= maxKey).Min(y => y.Value);
```

### Edit: Extension Method

If you're going to be using this a lot, you could turn it into an extension method you so can call it easily on any dictionary of type `Dictionary<int, double>`.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static double GetMaxInRange(this Dictionary<int, double> data, int minKey, int maxKey)
    {
        return data.Where(x => x.Key >= minKey && x.Key <= maxKey).Max(y => y.Value);
    }

    public static double GetMinInRange(this Dictionary<int, double> data, int minKey, int maxKey)
    {
        return data.Where(x => x.Key >= minKey && x.Key <= maxKey).Min(y => y.Value);
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var max = data.GetMaxInRange(3, 7);
var min = data.GetMinInRange(3, 7);
```

### Edit2:

If you want the `KeyValuePair<int, double>`, then this would be an option.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static KeyValuePair<int, double> GetMaxInRange(this Dictionary<int, double> data, int minKey, int maxKey)
    {
        return data.Where(x => x.Key >= minKey && x.Key <= maxKey).OrderByDescending(y => y.Value).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static KeyValuePair<int, double> GetMinInRange(this Dictionary<int, double> data, int minKey, int maxKey)
    {
        return data.Where(x => x.Key >= minKey && x.Key <= maxKey).OrderBy(y => y.Value).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: It will trigger a comparer on each iteration for both min and max LINQ evaluation that would raise a performance issue as the OP mentioned about the algorithm complexity concern already!

Comment: Using the second extension method I've given, it takes less than 300 ms to execute _both_ queries.

Comment: less than 300ms for 500,000 records?

Comment: Yes, linq is compact and simple but usually slower than foreach/for loop. But I am OK to do benchmark with both solutions.

Comment: Yes for 500K records.

Comment: I will do a benchmark of this solution, in comparison to a for loop. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a LinqPad5 example, but don't you want something like this?

```
  var inst = new Dictionary<int, double>();
inst.Add(1, 82.65);
inst.Add(2, 8.65);
inst.Add(3, 8.89);
inst.Add(4, 84.90);
inst.Add(5, 7.95);

var min = inst.Where(x => x.Value > 8).Min(x => x.Value);
Console.WriteLine(min);
var max = inst.Where(x => x.Value < 80).Max(x => x.Value);
Console.WriteLine(max);
```

Or if you're looking for the *key* you could do something like this:

```
var min = inst.Where(x => x.Value > 8).OrderBy(x => x.Value).First();
Console.WriteLine(min.Key);
var max = inst.Where(x => x.Value < 80).OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).First();
Console.WriteLine(max.Key);
```

However... there is a catch with the lather. How can you define *without certain doubt* the first key is the one you need? (but that's not my issue.. just a side question)

Answer (score 0):

I think this extension method for Dictionary can help you

```
static class DctExt {

    public static void GetKeysByValueInRange(this Dictionary<int,float> baseDct, int start, int end, out List<int> byMinValue, out List<int> byMaxValue) {
        byMinValue = new List<int>();
        byMaxValue = new List<int>();

        float max = GetMaxValue(baseDct, start, end);
        float min = GetMinValue(baseDct, start, end);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, float> kvp in baseDct) {
            if(kvp.Value == min) {
                byMinValue.Add(kvp.Key);
            }
            else if(kvp.Value == max) {
                byMaxValue.Add(kvp.Key);
            }
        }

    }

    private static float GetMaxValue(Dictionary<int,float> baseDct, int start, int end) {
        List<float> valuesOnRange = GetSpecificRange(baseDct, start, end);
        return valuesOnRange.Max();
    }

    private static float GetMinValue(Dictionary<int,float> baseDct, int start, int end) {
        List<float> valuesOnRange = GetSpecificRange(baseDct, start, end);
        return valuesOnRange.Min();
    }

    private static List<float> GetSpecificRange(Dictionary<int,float> dct, int start, int end) {
        List<float> res = new List<float>();

        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            res.Add(dct.ElementAt(i).Value);
        }

        return res;
    }

}
```

Here is the usage below

```
private static void Main() {

        Dictionary<int, float> dct = new Dictionary<int, float> {
            {1, 8.65f},
            {2, 7.65f},
            {3, 7.65f},
            {4, 8.90f},
            {5, 7.95f}
        };


        List<int> keysByMax = new List<int>();
        List<int> keysByMin = new List<int>();

        dct.GetKeysByValueInRange(1, 4, out keysByMin, out keysByMax);

        foreach (var item in keysByMin) {
            Console.Write($"min {item} ");
            // printst min 2 min 3
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (var item in keysByMax) {
            Console.Write($"max {item} ");
            //prints max 4
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If Only to get max and min, you can use:

```
    Dim myResult = Aggregate order In myDict Into Max(order.Value), Min(order.Value)

    'myResult.max for max and myResult.min as min
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get detail each dic, for min and max, may be you can try this:

```
    Dim myMinResult = From dic In myDic Where dic.Value = (Aggregate dicAgg In myDic Into Min(dicAgg.Value))
    Dim myMaxResult = From dic In myDic Where dic.Value = (Aggregate dicAgg In myDic Into Max(dicAgg.Value))
    MessageBox.Show("Min = key : " & myMinResult(0).Key.ToString & ", Value : " & myMinResult(0).Value.ToString)
    MessageBox.Show("Max = key : " & myMaxResult(0).Key.ToString & ", Value : " & myMaxResult(0).Value.ToString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class that encapsulates a `List<T>` and a [`ReaderWriterLock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlock), it is thread safe to use, and will perform much better than a `ConcurrentDictionary` for ranged queries. It will perform even better if single-element operations are avoided, so that the `ReaderWriterLock` is not acquired multiple times during a search or bulk-update. For example instead of:

```
for (int i = 25; i < 477; i++)
{
    if (list[i] > maxValue)
    {
        maxValue = list[i];
        maxIndex = i;
    }
}
```

...it is preferable to do it like this:

```
foreach (var entry in list.GetRange(25, 477))
{
    if (entry.Value > maxValue)
    {
        maxValue = entry.Value;
        maxIndex = entry.Index;
    }
}
```

...because the method `GetRange` acquires and releases the lock only once. Not only this is faster, but the results will also be more consistent, because it is guaranteed that no updates will happen during the enumeration of the range.

```
public class ConcurrentList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _list;
    private readonly ReaderWriterLock _lock = new ReaderWriterLock();

    public ConcurrentList()
    {
        _list = new List<T>();
    }

    public ConcurrentList(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        _list = new List<T>(collection);
    }

    public int Count => ReadSafe(list => list.Count);

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get => ReadSafe(list => list[index]);
        set => WriteSafe(list => list[index] = value);
    }

    public IEnumerable<(int Index, T Value)> GetRange(int from, int to)
    {
        using (new DisposableReader(_lock))
        {
            for (int i = from; i < to; i++)
            {
                yield return (i, _list[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Add(T item) => WriteSafe(list => list.Add(item));
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> r) => WriteSafe(list => list.AddRange(r));
    public void Clear() => WriteSafe(list => list.Clear());

    public void UpdateRange(IEnumerable<(int Index, T Value)> changes)
    {
        WriteSafe(list =>
        {
            foreach (var change in changes)
            {
                list[change.Index] = change.Value;
            }
        });
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        using (new DisposableReader(_lock))
        {
            foreach (var item in _list)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    public TResult ReadSafe<TResult>(Func<List<T>, TResult> function)
    {
        _lock.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.Infinite);
        try
        {
            return function(_list);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ReleaseReaderLock();
        }
    }

    public void WriteSafe(Action<List<T>> action)
    {
        _lock.AcquireWriterLock(Timeout.Infinite);
        try
        {
            action(_list);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ReleaseWriterLock();
        }
    }

    private struct DisposableReader : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ReaderWriterLock _lock;
        public DisposableReader(ReaderWriterLock obj)
        {
            _lock = obj;
            _lock.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        public void Dispose() => _lock.ReleaseReaderLock();
    }
}
```

I have used helper methods for acquiring and releasing the lock, to avoid repeating the `try - finally` block in every property and method. Of course this is not necessary, it is just a matter of style.

Comment: Theodor, I would like to test your suggestion but I am struggling at the moment to translate the class code into VB.NET. And does ```Readwriterlock``` can be substitued to ```ReadWriterLockSim```? [ReadWriterLockSim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Yeap, `ReadWriterLockSim` is definitely preferable!

Comment: `List` can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8). So if I manage to avoid writing after list creation, I can run parallelfor on it without issues. I will make the benchmark again using `list` and multithreaded reads.

Comment: Yes, if your data are immutable then indeed you can avoid thread synchronization altogether!